# How pass state and props between components more efficiently

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have ComponentA which renders a dumb componentB.

`ComponentA` is a class and `ComponentB` is a function that you pass props and state.

`ComponentA` has 20 props and 6 variables in state and to reduce code when pass props and state to `componentB` what is better?:

- OPTION A: pass all props and all state values?
- OPTION B: pass only the props that require and only the state values that require?

My question is whether, after passing all the props and the entire state, it consumes more memory or is less efficient.

Example:

```
class ComponentA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value1: false,
            ...
            value6: false,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
             ....
             <ComponentB props={this.props} state={this.state} />
             ....
          </div>
    }
}

export default class ComponentA



const ComponentB = ({ props, state }) => {

    return (
       <div>
          // Here use 12 props and 6 state values
          ...
       </div>
    );
};
export default ComponentB;
```

Comment: you need to only pass props that are relevant to `ComponentB` and not all the props

Comment: It is going to be less memory how you've written your example, because the same objects are reused, just a new reference to each object is created, rather than needing to create two new objects if you pass down only the props/state that are used.

Comment: If you were to ask about which is "better" from a developer standpoint, I'd recommend only passing the values that are used just as a convention. It makes it easier to see what your dependencies are, and the performance difference is negligible in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer option B, for the following reasons:

1) It keeps your child component (`ComponentB`) clean, such that you are not passing in unnecessary props, which will end up being unused.

2) You wouldn't want to cause any unnecessary re-render on `ComponentB` when any of the un-related props/state from the parents are updated.

Comment: #2 is actually a really good point... I use `{...this.state}` quite often to pass state to child props; never really thought about this potential blunder.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether, after passing all the props and the entire state, it consumes more memory or is less efficient.

Based solely on memory and performance of a single render, option A will be better.

In javascript, creating a new reference to an existing object is very cheap.

```js
var a = { value1: 1, value2: 2 };
var b = a;
```

In the example, only one object exists in memory, and two variables (pointers) reference the same value in memory. This is how option A would work in your question.

As for option B, it will require creating two new objects, one for props and one for state:

```js
var a = { value1: 1, value2: 2 };
var b = { value1: a.value1, value2: a.value2 };
```

This requires extra memory, since you have a new object AND a new variable, and not only the new variable.

It's worth noting that the performance difference will be negligible in 99.9% of cases. This same optimization could bite you when it comes to multiple renders, however, because any change to the parent's props or state would cause a rerender in the child, even if it's not a prop that the child cares about. I would generally recommend passing in only the required values from props and state for this reason. In React, most of your observable performance problems will happen due to unnecessary rerendering, not memory consumption.